# “Ich sehe in das Bild, dann denke ich dran” or “Ich sehe im Bild, dann denke ich dran”

Tags: grammatical-case, verb-usage

It’s clear to me that we use accusative for movements from place to place, and dative for being at a place.

But for such verbe like *sehen* as above, should we use accusative or dative?

Comment: "In" das Bild sehen ist falsch. Man sieht ein Bild an. Den Bepispielsätzen fehlt auch ein "Wenn". Wolltest Du sagen "Wenn ich das Bild sehe, denke ich daran"?

Comment: What is the english sentence you want to translate? Both sentences you provided in the question sound odd.

Comment: Possibly related (depending on what the question actually is about): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7675

Answer (score 0):

If the question is *"Wohin sehe ich?"*, you use accusative. If the question is *"Wo sehe ich etwas?"*, you use dative.

Normally, you say

1. "Ich sehe auf das Bild." (*Wohin?*, Akkusativ)
2. "Ich sehe auf dem Bild dies und das." (*Wo?*, Dativ)

If you mean you look into a 3D world of things shown in the picture, you may also say in colloquial speech "Ich sehe in das Bild." like "Ich sehe in den Spiegel", and "Ich sehe dies und das im Bild."

Comment: "im Bild" is very common, without referring to 3D at all.

Comment: ich hab lange überlegt, wann man *im* und *auf* nimmt, und denke, bei *im* hast du einen gedachten Raum vor dir, jedoch bei *auf* einfach eine Fläche.

Comment: Nicht unbedingt. Lös dich mal von Bild selbst. Ein Bild hat oft irgendwo einen vorstellbaren 3D-Raum. Nimm das Beispiel: "In der Abbildung/Skizze/Karikatur unten sehen sie..." Dies ist äquivalent dazu, aber in keiner dieser ist ein 3D-Raum der Normalfall (ehestens noch in der Karikatur).

Comment: `auf dem Bild` wird nicht in diesem Sinn benutzt. Du kannst sagen: `Auf dem Bild sitzt eine Mücke.` oder `Auf dem Bild sehe ich eine Mücke.` Dann hat die Mücke aber nichts mit dem Bild*in*halt zu tun, sondern fliegt im nächsten Moment weiter. Bezüglich des Bild*in*halts verwendet man immer *in*, denn ein Bild ist ideell eine beschränkte Fläche. Als solche hat sie ein `Inneres`: den Bildinhalt. Wenn überhaupt, dann könnte man bei sehr dicken Kollagen ein `auf` akzeptieren, aber eher nicht.

Comment: @Toscho: nein, es ist völlig normal zu sagen "ich sehe auf dem Bild blabla..." Stimme falkb zu. Außerdem geht es in der Frage um Dativ und Akkusativ.

Comment: @SchcS Siehe https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=im+Bild%2C+auf+dem+Bild&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cim%20Bild%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauf%20dem%20Bild%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Toscho: das ist nicht repräsentativ, Gegenbeweis Google: 25M `im Bild` : 253M `auf dem Bild` and the winner is *auf dem Bild* ;) aber man sollte das Thema wirklich mal in einer eigenen Frage aufarbeiten

Comment: @falkb Dann schau dir mal die Ergebnisse zu `auf dem Bild` an. Das ist ganz viel generisches Material da. ngrams liefern sowas nicht. Das heißt nicht, dass ngrams der Weisheit letzter Schluss sind, aber solange du mein ngram nicht inhaltlich entkräftigst, ist es ein stichhaltiges Argument.

Comment: findet ngram nicht auch "ich bin im Bilde"?

Comment: Ich habe das Gefühl, dass "auf" dem Bild eine etwas distanziertere Betrachtung wiedergibt, während "in" dem Bild andeutet, dass man sich stärker auf das Werk einlässt.  "Auf dem Bild von Obama war seine Frau im Hintergrund" vs. "Im Bild der Monalisa sind im Hintergrund Hügel zu sehen".  Beides geht definitiv und ist nicht ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @Alfe: das meinte ich mit "3D world of things". *auf dem* meint die Abbildung, *im* das Objekt selbst. Daraus folgt dein Gefühl der Distanz, denn die (2D-)Abbildung ist nicht das Objekt selbst.